# Why am I getting "access forbidden" when pinging SendGrid API?

Tags: php, json, authentication, curl, sendgrid

I'm trying to make a basic call to SendGrid API v3 in PHP. I do have an API Key that has been confirmed to work. My code:

```
$url = "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/template/";
$access_token = "example";

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Authorization: Bearer $access_token",
    "Content-Type: application/json"
));

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ($status != 200){
    die('Could not connect to endpoint.');
}

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);

curl_close($curl);
```

According to the SendGrid API documentation I should get a JSON response such as:

```
{
    "name": "new template name"
}
```

However, I am receiving this instead:

```
{
    "errors":[
        {
            "field": null,
            "message": "access forbidden"
        }]
}
```

The status returned is 403, which isn't even documented on the API.

If my API Key is correct (which it is, triple checked), then why am I getting an access forbidden error? Am I missing a header?

Comment: Does your API Key have the proper permissions? https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/API_Keys/api_key_permissions_list.html

Comment: That ended up being an issue. I will submit an answer. Had to create a new API Key with the correct permissions

Comment: I am also getting 403 access forbidden response from sendgrid API.
But getting the same response when trying it here: https://sendgrid.api-docs.io/v3.0/webhooks/test-event-notification-settings